# Sphinx autodoc module : how to hide source link of an autodocumented function or method?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When using the `autodoc` module and the `autofunction` feature to document a function, a link to the source code of this function appears next to the documentation.

I use `autofunction` like this, with no option:

```
.. autofunction:: CLT.compute_ABBD
```

I want the docstring to appear on the HTML page, but I don't want the link to the source to appear. I didn't figured out what are the options I should give to `autofunction` or set up in `conf.py`.

Comment: I don't want the source to appear because the documentation is dedicated to students. The docstring of the fonction gives inputs and outputs as well as the instructions of the exercice. However, the correction is included in the file I used to generate the doc.

Comment: Is the `sphinx.ext.viewcode` extension enabled in conf.py? If it is, you need to disable it (remove it from the `extensions` variable).

Comment: Thanks mzjn, that is the solution. I was looking for something to add, it was something to remove I had to look for.